# Invoking `mvn package` directly works, but fails through Makefile

Tags: java, maven, makefile

I'm having a really weird issue. I have a simple Makefile

```
compile:
    mvn package
```

When I run `mvn package` everything works just fine. But when I run `make compile` I get:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.6:jar (default-jar) on project flex-plugins-api-server: Execution default-jar of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.6:jar failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.6:jar: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
```

I'm very confused why running the package goal through makefile is causing maven-jar-plugin to fail

Comment: `make compile` is running `mvn package`, not `mvn compile`. What happens if you run `mvn package` from the command line?

Comment: @tgdavies Sorry typo; I meant `mvn package`

Comment: Might help to run mvn with the -X option and see if that gives you any ideas.

Comment: Is the JVM used properly installed?

Comment: I suspect it is due to the different config for `sh` which is the default `make` shell vs. `bash` or whichever shell you are using in your terminal.